# ¿Cómo colocar una imagen sobre otra con CSS o CSS3?

Tags: css, html5, css3, canvas

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Cuento con una imagen base que está en formato PNG, esta imagen no tiene fondo. Es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, ¿cómo puedo hacer para colocar otra imagen arriba de esa pero que la imagen que quede arriba quede superpuesta con css?, esta sería la imagen que va arriba en formato JPG:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que quede como si el diseño de pantera quedara impreso sobre el sueter, ¿cómo podría hacer esto con CSS3 o que tecnología me recomiendan utilizar para hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar poner algo asi. la imagen del puma que quieres poner deberías quitarle el fondo para que la puedas pasar bien al de la imagen de la chaqueta , ya lo que queda es probar con opacity , prueba asi a ver si te gusta el resultado (el opacity se lo pones en imagen a superpone) el css

```css
.ImagenAsuperPoner{
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  top: 40px;
  left : 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}


 .imagen1
{
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
```

```html
 <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1203257/1718/i/450/depositphotos_17180113-stock-photo-black-background.jpg" class='imagen1'/>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/57/f4/05/57f4053fd210be8a71beb67f5e16af6d.jpg" class="ImagenAsuperPoner"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar un alcance similar a este. La clave está en usar un div para la segunda imagen y utilizar la propiedad `background-image` en lugar de la etiqueta `img`; esto nos da la posibilidad de utilizar la propiedad `background-blend-mode` que nos servirá para fusionar ambas imagenes con el valor `screen` y por último manipulamos el color con la propiedad `background-color` para dar el mismo color de la primera imagen.

Déjame saber si tienes alguna duda sobre este alcance.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.primary {
  position: absolute;
}

.secondary {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON9KO.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 76%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 129px;
    height: 206px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-blend-mode: screen;
    background-color: #252222;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBi5R.png" class="primary">
  <div class="secondary">
  </div>
```

Comment: Buenos días, @Juan García es util tu respuesta, pero en este caso conservo el ancho y el alto de la class="secondary" lo deje al 100% en ambas, ahora como hago para que se corte el diseño de pantera en todo el sueter, mejor dicho como puedo hacer para que el diseño de pantera quede como impreso por encima del sueter con el 100% del alto y ancho, allí en la pregunta voy adjuntar un ejemplo de como debería quedar, para ver si me pueden ayudar de alguna forma a terminarlo.

Comment: La única forma de hacer eso con css es usando clip-path, lo que hace esta propiedad es recortar un elemento a partir de unas coordenadas o medidas que le especifiques como valor

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo usando CSS grid, si colocas dos elementos en el mismo track se van a superponer, generan lo que se conoce como contexto de apilamiento, puedes controlar el orden usando `z-index`, la ventaja de usar grid para esto es que los elementos siguen dentro del flujo y su espacio sigue siendo considerado con respecto a los elementos hermanos.

Para aprender sobre grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

```css
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
}

img:nth-child(1){
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}

img:nth-child(2){
  width: 150px;
  height:150px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBi5R.png" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON9KO.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```